# POST file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm not so familiar with PHP, but i'm learning and trying to make an input field which uploads image to my server.

On HTML side i'll post to another file:

```
<form method="post" action="functions.php" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="file" name="pilt">
    <button type="submit" name="submitform">
</form>
```

Actually form has a lot more components which are posted along with them, but for simplicity, i've left them out (every other element is posted as needed).

In the functions.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
    $name = basename($_FILES['pilt']['name']);
    echo $name;
}
```

then nothing is printed, meaning that $name is empty. I followed [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) guide, but as already naming fails then obviously fails other code as well. Can anyone point out why this does not work?

Comment: You forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Comment: THANK YOU, that did the trick!